# Number Theory : Do integers $s$ and $t$ exist?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was solving some basic number theory problems from [Number Theory by Rosen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321500318) and was stuck on the following exercise problem :

> Show that if $a$ and $b$ are odd positive integers and b does not divide a , then there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $a = bs + t$, where t is odd and |t| < b

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Hint: if the remainder $t$ is even then replace it by $\,t\!-\!b,\,$ which has opposite parity since $\,b\,$ is odd, i.e. i.e. $\ a = bs+t = b(s\!+\!1) + t\!-\!b\ \ $

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division

Comment: Thanks a ton @BillDubuque :)